# jQuery how to make slideToggle applies one each item

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this toggle fadein fadeout applies on each `items`block? when I click anyone, it applies all of them.
Could someone please help ? Thanks

**[Online Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/az8T7/)**

```
     <div class="items">
        <div class="warp">
            <span class="change">Tester</span>
             <span class="click">expand</span>
        </div>
        <div class="invisible">
            <div class="red"> red </div>
            <div class="black"> black </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="warp">
            <span class="change">Tester</span>
             <span class="click">expand</span>
        </div>
        <div class="invisible">
            <div class="red"> red </div>
            <div class="black"> black </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('.invisible').hide();
 $('.warp').addClass('bg');

$(".warp").click(function () {
        $(".invisible").slideToggle("slow", function () {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $('.warp').removeClass('bg');
            }else{

              $('span.click').css('visibility', 'visible');  
              $('.warp').addClass('bg');
            }
         });

    $('span.click').css('visibility', 'hidden');      
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make this toggle fadein fadeout applies on each itemsblock?
>   when I click anyone, it applies all of them.

This is because you use `$(".invisible")` which selects all elements with the class `invisible`. You have to find the element related to your toggle element(your `.warp` element), which in your case would be like this: `$warp.next(".invisible")`.

See the updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/az8T7/1/).

Updated your jQuery code:

```
$(".warp").click(function () {
    var $warp = $(this);

    $warp.next(".invisible").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $warp.removeClass('bg');
        }else{            
            $warp.find('span.click').css('visibility', 'visible');  
            $warp.addClass('bg');
        }
    });

    $warp.find('span.click').css('visibility', 'hidden');      
});
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer :-) Will I have the same outcome if I use each function ?

Comment: @olo Could you clearify the question? Where would you use `each`? PS: Don't forget to mark the answer :)

Comment: yes! marked :-) I mean, if possible to use `each` to achieve the same result. thanks again

Comment: Well, that would just have been more lines of code. You still would have needed to find the relative elements based on `$(this)`. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

HERE: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faSLa/)

jquery:

```
$('.invisible').hide();
$(".warp").click(function () {
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle("slow", function () {
            $(this).prev('div').toggleClass('bg');
            $(this).prev('div').find('.click').slideToggle("fast", function () {});
        });
});
```