# jQuery how to make slideToggle applies one each item and hide others when one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have asked a question here: 
[**jQuery how to make slideToggle applies one each item**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532223/jquery-how-to-make-slidetoggle-applies-one-each-item/16532308#16532308)

and I have got the right answer here: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/az8T7/3/)

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="warp">
        <span class="change">Tester</span>
         <span class="click">expand</span>
    </div>
    <div class="invisible">
        <div class="red"> red </div>
        <div class="black"> black </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="items">
    <div class="warp">
        <span class="change">Tester</span>
         <span class="click">expand</span>
    </div>
    <div class="invisible">
        <div class="red"> red </div>
        <div class="black"> black </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="items">
    <div class="warp">
        <span class="change">Tester</span>
         <span class="click">expand</span>
    </div>
    <div class="invisible">
        <div class="red"> red </div>
        <div class="black"> black </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".warp").click(function () {
    var $warp = $(this);

    $warp.next(".invisible").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $warp.removeClass('bg');
        }else{            
            $warp.find('span.click').css('visibility', 'visible');  
            $warp.addClass('bg');
        }
    });

    $warp.find('span.click').css('visibility', 'hidden');      
  });
```

My question is that, when one is selected how to slideToggle the other `invisible` divs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select visible elements with `:visible` like that :

```
var siblings = $warp.parent().siblings('.items').find('.invisible:visible')

siblings.slideToggle("slow", function () {
    var parent = $(this).prev('.warp');
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        parent.removeClass('bg');
    }else{            
        parent.find('span.click').css('visibility', 'visible');  
        parent.addClass('bg');
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/az8T7/4/

Comment: thanks for the answer, when select the opened one, it doesn't close

Comment: Edited my answer, it work but i'm not so sure it is good to use taht much selector. There is probly an other way arround.